# Is there anyway to block UI Thread like as Window.ShowDialog() WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, multithreading, showdialog

I'm developing a WPF application without using Window.Show() or Window.ShowDialog(), it's just simple a MainWindow and load to specified UserControls to place holders.

But the problem is when app shows a control into place holder, it doesn't block thread like as Window.ShowDialog(), I mean when a user control is embedded into MainWindow, it can close to back to mainscreen like this:

```
// Invoke foo control into placeholder
if (!ShowFooControl())
{
// TODO A: if control's result return false 
FooA();
}

// TODO B:just call after foo control closed
FooB();

return true;
```

FooB() is only called after Foo Control has been closed.

FooA() is only called after Foo Control has been closed and has DialogResult = false.

What can I do to simulate Window.ShowDialog for my case.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to block everything but your current usercontrol? Is that usercontrol in a different window?

Comment: I have really some problems understanding what you are doing so from what I've understood you have a window where you show some controls I presume on user action and you want that if a control i shown the rest of the window is frozen, what about using the IsEnabled property of the controls with an opportune viewmodel so that when the control is shown the rest of the controls on the window have the IsEnabled property set to false?

Comment: hi @Master117 yup, that what I want: block other except current UserControl that invoking to MainWindow. Thanks

Comment: hi @Sabrina_cs I updated my question. The problem is I want the ShowFooControl() has something like Window.ShowDialog() that can block other code until it closed. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried manually blocking your other stuff? But the way you do it all your controls run in the same thread. Most elements have .disable() or something similar.

Comment: @QuocNguyen, there is Infragistics's xamDialogWindow which I believe you're after. You might want to check their samples (for free). Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok understood, the best way to obtain what you want is what I told in my first answer.
To better explain you what it means I've made a small WPF application as a sample.
My application has a main window and 3 different user controls each of them with some functionality and a close button. 
In the main window I've put three buttons that create and show the controls inside the window and set a boolean property in the window that locks any other control when a User control is shown and enables all controls after the user control is closed. You can download the sample using the following link
http://blogs.dotnetwork.it/sabrina/download/SampleCode/DisableControls.zip